# simple get json_decode array value , error no idea

Tags: php

```
<?php

$playerBox = json_decode($_POST['player_data'], true);

echo print_r($playerBox);

echo $playerBox['name'];

?>
```

i am sending a array by ajax to php , this is my php code and my intention here is to get each value and create a html p for it.

but i am having trouble getting each value , i have no idea why m every one can use this to get it by i cant.

here is the $_POST['player_data') at print_r

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Jonny
            [number] => 27
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => dx
            [number] => 28
        )

)
```

the error i get

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\objecttest\directory\class-mail.php on line <i>7</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0004</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>135312</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\objecttest\directory\class-mail.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\class-mail.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
</table></font>
```

how do i get each value and create like this ?

```
id   name    number

1   Johnny     27

2   dx         28
```

Comment: echo $playerBox[0]['name']; use will get right value

Answer (score 0):

You have to access your array using index number like this

```
 $playerBox[0]['id'];
$playerBox[0]['name'];
$playerBox[0]['number'];
```

Comment: why i have to put the 0 ?

Comment: use for loop to iterate in records. 0 is index number.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)  iterate over arrays and get the each index values

```
   <table border="1px" >
      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Number</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
<?php

  foreach($playerBox as $play)
  {
   ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $play['id']; ?> </td>
       <td><?php echo $play['name']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $play['number']; ?></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
  }
 ?>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```